# "Math Processing Error" in red instead of a TeX formula

Tags: bug, math-display

I just noted that `\binom{}{}` does not work, as before, and as it should:
$$
          \binom{3}{2}
$$
What I typed within double dollar signs is : `\binom{3}{2}` which used to work. What I now see is just an error message ("Math error" or similar) in red.

Comment: I see it working above.

Comment: @Scortchi: So is it something wrong with my local setup, by the way, using firefox now ... but now, after switching to chrome (this is windows), it works ...

Comment: Sorry, no idea, though it certainly sounds like it.

Comment: I am using Firefox and it's working for me.

Comment: @Glen_b: do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it also works for me in Fx. Reboot? This always help for 99% IT problems ;)

Comment: I just turned off everything but noscript but it still shows up okay. (I really doubt the couple of things noscript is blocking would have any effect on mathjax.)

Comment: I had the same issue w/ `\binom{N}{K}` (& also w/ `{N \choose K}`) a week or two ago. Then it started working again. I have no idea what the issue was.

Comment: Try changing the math renderer you're using: right click on the image & choose Math Settings ... Math Renderer ... HTML-CSS

Comment: What sometimes helps is to clear the browser's cache. Can you try that and see if it helps?

Comment: Yes! thanks, it did work now.  I saw is on multiple machines, though. Will se tomorrow on the other machines.

Comment: Cool. Please report after you test it further. I will then write an answer so that we have a standard reference for this problem. But I want to make sure that it works.

Comment: Also, when it did not work, what symptoms did you experience? Did you see some error message instead of the formula or the dollar signs and latex code in between in plain text?

Comment: What I see is just an error message ("Math error" or similar) in red.

Comment: Now, in firefox on the other machine, cleared cache, worked here too.